# Keeping the Text Typed On Input Back on Form when Submitted (data persistency, state) on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there an easier way to keep data when posted?

Issue: I enter a text inside the input box HTML element that I know will fail validation such as above 50 string, then click on "submit" button (page loads): validation shows up

> The field First Name must be a string with a maximum length of 50.

. Then

> HTML text input element is 'empty'

Model (User model)

```
public class User
{

[StringLength(50)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter the first name"), Display(Name = "First Name")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z '-.]*$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid first name characters.")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }


}
```

Controler (two methods one for get and the other POST)

UserController

```
public Create()

{
  return View();

}
//edited per suggestion
public Create(User user)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       return View(user);
    }

    db.User.Add(user);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View("Index");

}
```

Create View

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "First name" } })

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: The code you have shown works fine and if you return the view then the textbox will show the previous value the user entered. If its not working for you then its because of code you have not shown, or you have a custom `EditorTemplate`

Comment: None of that. But you're right Editorfor worked I just had to return View(user) at the end instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of that is the correct way to persist form state with the exception of

```
[HttpPost]
public Create(User user)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       return View(user);
    }

    db.User.Add(user);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View("Index");

}
```

Comment: Hello Steven. Thanks for the tip. I did that. But so when I type a name that didn't pass the validation. Then I click on submit button. The input box for becomes empty.

Comment: And if you put a breakpoint inside the POST method, the user maintains all property values? All your text boxes are inside the form on the view, correct?

Comment: Yes it's inside @using (Html.BeginForm()). And at break point on post, it keeps the value, but when I continue, it's blank.... this only happens when I have a validation error (for example I typed in more 50 characters on the first name). It saves it on the database if there was no error, then it keeps the info on form inputs.

Comment: Just throwing this out here, instead of using EditorFor, try TextBoxFor

Comment: Ok I reverted to EditorFor and returned View(user); at the end that worked.